# Move child in Firebase from top to bottom

Tags: android, firebase

I am working on an application that sends notification from Device A to Device B. Now once the notification is Accepted by one of the UID mentioned in the image, I want to move that UID to the bottom of the list. How do I move a UID from its place to bottom place in Firebase? Suppose 1st UID accepts the request, I want to move that UID to last. [image]

Comment: But why u want to move that to last? Set a child under uid & just change its value to yes when a request is accepted.

Comment: You want to move the first element to last in Firebase Console?

Comment: @Raj Actually I have to move  I have to reiterate through all records again & again

Comment: @AlexMamo Just inside 'all', I want to move first UID to last

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, there is no way in which you can change the order of your elements in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/). Because you have used the `push()` method to add the elements to the database, you need to know that the pushed ids are based on time and are order chronologically and you cannot change this behaviour.

To solve this, you need to query your database to get all elements and then order them in anyway you want.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?